# Two render methods works at the same time in two screens

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to make a Tick Tack Toe game in LibGDX and I want to move from the screen where the user play (PlayGround) to the screen which displays the results (End) but the render method in the PlayGround screen is still called although I already changed the screen to End. After debugging I relaized that only the show method in the End screen is called but the render method is still called from the PlayGround not from End.

PlayGround code :

```
public class PlayGround implements Screen {

MainMenu game;
Stage stage;
Texture gridTex;
Image gridImage ;
TextButton restart ;
TextButtonStyle style ;
String turn ;
SpriteBatch batch;
Zone[] zones = new Zone[9];
End end;
XO game1;




public PlayGround(MainMenu game){
    this.game = game;
}



@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {


}

@Override
public void show() {

    game1 = new XO();
    end = new End(this);

    //Draw Grid
    gridTex = new Texture("images/playground/grid.png");
    gridImage = new Image(gridTex);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    gridImage.setPosition(40, 100);

    //Draw Restart

    style = new TextButtonStyle();
    style.font = MainMenu.defaultFont;
    TextureRegionDrawable drawable =new TextureRegionDrawable(Zone.atlas.findRegion("restart"));
    style.up  = drawable ;
    style.down = drawable ;
    restart = new TextButton("Restart",style);

    //Create the Zones
    zones[0] = new Zone(50, 378);
    zones[1] = new Zone(151, 378);
    zones[2] = new Zone(251, 378);
    zones[3] = new Zone(50, 242);
    zones[4] = new Zone(151, 242);
    zones[5] = new Zone(251, 242);
    zones[6] = new Zone(50, 108);
    zones[7] = new Zone(151, 108);
    zones[8] = new Zone(251, 108);

    restart.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < zones.length ; i++)
            {
                zones[i].setPlayer(0) ;
                zones[i].setClicked(false);
                zones[i].getImage().setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(Zone.atlas.findRegion("empty"))); 
            }
            Zone.counter = 1 ;

            return true;

        }

        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

        }
    });


    //Creating the stage and adding actors
    stage = new Stage(380, 630, true);
    stage.addActor(gridImage);
    for(int i = 0 ; i< zones.length ; i++)
        stage.addActor(zones[i].getImage());
    stage.addActor(restart);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);




}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    //It clears the older screen
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    System.out.println(Zone.counter);
    if(Zone.counter%2==0)
    {turn = "O's TURN";}
    else
    {turn = "X's TURN";}

    check();

    //Drawing the stage and it's children's
    batch.begin();
    stage.draw();
    batch.end();

    batch.begin();
    MainMenu.title.draw(batch,turn, 114 , 570);
    batch.end();

    //Fires the listeners
    stage.act(delta);

}

public void check()
{
    //Horizontal
    for(int i = 0 ; i<7;i += 3)
    {
        if(zones[i].getPlayer()==1 && zones[i+1].getPlayer()==1 && zones[i+2].getPlayer()==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Player 1 wins");
            End.setWinner(1);
            stage.clear();
            game1.setScreen(end);

        }
        else if(zones[i].getPlayer()==2 && zones[i+1].getPlayer()==2 && zones[i+2].getPlayer()==2)
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 wins");
            End.setWinner(2);
            stage.clear();
            game1.setScreen(end);
        }
        else if (Zone.counter == 10)
        {
            stage.clear();
            game1.setScreen(end);
        }
    }
    //Vertical :
    for(int i = 0 ; i<3;i++)
    {
        if(zones[i].getPlayer()==1 && zones[i+3].getPlayer()==1 && zones[i+6].getPlayer()==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Player 1 wins");
            End.setWinner(1);
            stage.clear();
            game1.setScreen(end);
        }
        else if(zones[i].getPlayer()==2 && zones[i+3].getPlayer()==2 && zones[i+6].getPlayer()==2)
        {
            System.out.println("Player 2 wins");
            End.setWinner(2);
            stage.clear();
            game1.setScreen(end);
        }
        else if (Zone.counter == 10)
        {System.out.println("Tie");
        stage.clear();
        game1.setScreen(end);
        }
    }
    //Diagonal LeftToRight
    if(zones[0].getPlayer()==1 && zones[4].getPlayer()==1 && zones[8].getPlayer()==1)
    {System.out.println("Player 1 wins");
    End.setWinner(1);
    stage.clear();
    game1.setScreen(end);
    }
    if(zones[0].getPlayer()==2 && zones[4].getPlayer()==2 && zones[8].getPlayer()==2)
    {System.out.println("Player 2 wins");
    End.setWinner(2);
    stage.clear();
    game1.setScreen(end);
    }

    //Diagonal RightToLeft
    if(zones[2].getPlayer()==1 && zones[4].getPlayer()==1 && zones[6].getPlayer()==1)
    {System.out.println("Player 1 wins");
    End.setWinner(1);
    stage.clear();
    game1.setScreen(end);
    }
    if(zones[2].getPlayer()==2 && zones[4].getPlayer()==2 && zones[6].getPlayer()==2)
    {System.out.println("Player 2 wins");
    End.setWinner(2);
    stage.clear();
    game1.setScreen(end);
    }
}
```

Code from the End screen :

```
package com.teamthawra.www.Screens;



public class End implements Screen {

static int winner = 0;
SpriteBatch batch;
static Stage stage;
XO game;
MainMenu main;
PlayGround playground;

public End (PlayGround playground) {

    this.playground = playground;
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    System.out.println("Rendering in end");
    if (winner == 1){
        batch.begin();
        MainMenu.title.draw(batch, "X WON!", 114, 570);
        batch.end();
    }
    else if (winner == 2){
        batch.begin();
        MainMenu.title.draw(batch, "O WON!", 114, 570);
        batch.end();
    }
    else {
        batch.begin();
        MainMenu.title.draw(batch, "It's a tie", 114, 570);
        batch.end(); }
    batch.begin();  
    MainMenu.title.draw(batch, "Press anywhere to continue", 114, 300);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {


}

@Override
public void show() {
    System.out.println("I am at end");
    game = new XO();
    main = new MainMenu(this);
    stage = new Stage(380, 630 , true);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    stage.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        stage.clear();
    game.setScreen(main);
            return true;
    }

    public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

   }
  });

    }

public static void setWinner(int winner) {
    End.winner = winner;
}

public static int getWinner() {
    return winner;
}





    }
```

Sorry for adding all the code , because I am a beginner and this is my first program in LibGDX I don't know where the problem is exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not entirely sure, but my best guess is that calling **setScreen()** on **game1** (a new object of type **XO**) is the problem.

If I'm correct, you should be calling **setScreen()** on the same object of time Game (or that inherited from LibGdx's Game) that called **setScreen()** for your screen PlayGround.

For example, if you had a menu Screen and from there you went the playground using this command:

```
game.setScreen(playGroundScreen);
```

you should be switching screens over the same game object like this:

```
game.setScreen(endScreen);
```

instead of creating a new variable (like you did with game1).

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you so much sir!
It amazingly worked :)
I just made the game variable in the main menu public and static then I used it in playground and end to call the setScreen method.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you are learning libgdx it could be useful to you having a look a this project: https://github.com/edesdan/libgdx-playground . It's a basic implementation structure of a libgdx game. You can use it as starting point for your game.